# XSLT transform, adding wrapper around child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have this xml snippet

```
            <cybox:Properties xsi:type="FileObj:FileObjectType">
                <FileObj:File_Path>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\9b581244f88e7f51d55e7654cf443ffb.exe</FileObj:File_Path>
                <FileObj:Size_In_Bytes>2374144</FileObj:Size_In_Bytes>
                <FileObj:File_Format>exe</FileObj:File_Format>
                <FileObj:Hashes>
                    <cyboxCommon:Hash>
                        <cyboxCommon:Type>MD5</cyboxCommon:Type>
                        <cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>9b581244f88e7f51d55e7654cf443ffb</cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>
                    </cyboxCommon:Hash>
                    <cyboxCommon:Hash>
                        <cyboxCommon:Type>SHA1</cyboxCommon:Type>
                        <cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>9c34d683700476ebafd7cb08bb460947b55b1af1</cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>
                    </cyboxCommon:Hash>
                </FileObj:Hashes>
            </cybox:Properties>
```

I'm trying to turn it into this:

```
<cybox:Properties xsi:type="FileObj:FileObjectType">
       <File_Object>
            <FileObj:File_Path>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\9b581244f88e7f51d55e7654cf443ffb.exe</FileObj:File_Path>
                <FileObj:Size_In_Bytes>2374144</FileObj:Size_In_Bytes>
                <FileObj:File_Format>exe</FileObj:File_Format>
                <FileObj:Hashes>
                    <cyboxCommon:Hash>
                        <cyboxCommon:Type>MD5</cyboxCommon:Type>
                        <cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>9b581244f88e7f51d55e7654cf443ffb</cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>
                    </cyboxCommon:Hash>
                    <cyboxCommon:Hash>
                        <cyboxCommon:Type>SHA1</cyboxCommon:Type>
                        <cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>9c34d683700476ebafd7cb08bb460947b55b1af1</cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>
                    </cyboxCommon:Hash>
            </FileObj:Hashes>
        </File_Object>
    </cybox:Properties>
```

So I know I have to grab the `</cybox:Properties>` element by the xsi:type which is fine, however I don't really know how to add the `<File_Object>` wrapper around everything under `<cybox:Properties>`

Comment: Please post your code so that we can add to it, rather than write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping content is as simple as inserting the open and close nodes into a template:

```
<xsl:template match="InputNode">
    <InputNode>
        <wrapper>
        <xsl:copy-of select="children nodes..."/>
        </wrapper>
    </InputNode>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, the solution to your problem could be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cybox="http://localhost/cybox" xmlns:FileObj="http://localhost/FileObj" xmlns:cyboxCommon="http://localhost/cyboxCommon" xmlns:xsi="http://localhost/xsi">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="cybox:Properties"></xsl:apply-templates>
...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cybox:Properties">
    <cybox:Properties xsi:type="FileObj:FileObjectType">
        <File_Object>
            <xsl:copy-of select="FileObj:*"/>
        </File_Object>
    </cybox:Properties>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```